# Finding Step Count Function with Ceiling/Floor Functions

Tags: big-o

I came across a challenge problem in a textbook that I am having trouble with. I need to find the step-count function in terms of n which counts the number of times the print procedure is called. Below is the pseudocode.

```
function EXAMPLE( some positive int n )
 i <- 1
 while i <= n do
      i <- i * 2
      j <- 1
      while j <= i do
          j <- j + 1
          print("something")
```

I tried starting with finding the number of times print is called with respect to n for a few cases:

```
n  T(n)
1   2
2   6
3   6
4   14
5   14
```

I'm sure that a ceiling/floor function with n is involved somehow for the first while loop, but am unsure as to how to proceed from there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop: `j` increases from 1 to `i` --- runs `i` times.

Outer loop: classic logarithmic loop. `i` increases as a power of two until it becomes greater than or equal to `n`.

[image]

So your guess was correct. Note that `i` is doubled *before* the inner loop instead of after; this has the effect of doubling the number of calls. Total number of calls to `print` is then:

[image]

Test values:

```
n    T(n)
----------
1    2
2    6
3    6
4    14
5    14
6    14
7    14
8    30
9    30
10   30
...
```

Due to the floor operator, `T(n)` only increases when `n` reaches the next power-of-2.